# Magento: what changes when a product gets indexed available/unavailable?

Tags: magento

So, I'm trying to find out what changes in the database tables when an enabled product (i.e. available in `catalog_product_flat_1`) goes to quantity 0 or to quantity X > 0.

I didn't find anything related to stock in `catalog_product_flat_1`, but I did find that tables `cataloginventory_stock_item`, `cataloginventory_stock_status`, `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx` have related columns.

I see that `cataloginventory_stock_status` has `qty` and `status` reflected in the admin (i.e. when you update stock qty in admin, it gets reflected here), but `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx` doesn't change with stock update in the admin. I'm guessing this gets updated when the re-index happens? I tried changing `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`'s `qty` and `status`, but an out-of-stock item on the front-end doesn't immediately become available.

So, my question is:

What are the changes made in the DB tables when an enabled product (i.e. listed on front-end) becomes available (qty>0) or unavailable (qty=0)? I'm trying to see if we can update stock levels and have changes reflected immediately without re-indexing the products. We use Magento EE 1.12.

Answer (score 0):

One way to determine this would be to enable the MySQL `general_query_log` - then you can see the actual DML statements.

You'll first need to enable `general_log` and then you can specify the actual file:

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log

Comment: Unfortunately, the test DB is on the same server as our production server.. I read about how to enable it and just disable it for specific connections, but I think I'll hold off on that option for now.